# How to count the occurrences of a regex match over time in sumologic?

Tags: regex, sumologic

I have logs that have a particular error string that I would like to capture. I want to track the total errors over time and not care about any particular error because the error message contains an `id` which means every error is seen as different.

```
_collector="Service" 
| parse regex "error: (?<error>.+?(?=,))"
| timeslice 15m
| sum(error) as total_errors by _timeslice
| count by _timeslice, total_errors
```

The problem with this is that it does not correctly group the errors over time and instead shows a graph where each line is the separate error.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

So this turned out to be a case of over complicating things.

```
_collector="Service" "error:"
| timeslice 5m
| count by _timeslice
```

We don't need a regex because we don't care about the specific value.